# How many "After Update" trigger can be written on a single table

Tags: sql-server-2008

How many "After Update" trigger can be written on a single table?

If more than 1 then how it will decide which update trigger to run first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The first and last AFTER triggers to be executed on a table can be specified by using `sp_settriggerorder`. Only one first and one last AFTER trigger for each INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operation can be specified on a table. **If there are other AFTER triggers on the same table, they are randomly executed.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>